# Understanding a Java Regular Expression

Tags: java

I am matching this expression with emails with the below format.

```
From: me@gmail.com
To: you@gmail.com

<Body of the email>
```

Any help to match this email would be of great help.

Comment: If you are dealing with emails in Java your best choice is to use JavaMail API. You can check the [project home](https://java.net/projects/javamail/pages/Home) to get the API and documentation. After that you can post your question here if you have any doubts.
If you are trying to parse a String or file you can use [Apache Mime4J](http://james.apache.org/mime4j/apidocs/org/apache/james/mime4j/parser/MimeStreamParser.html)

Comment: Read starting here: http://www.regular-expressions.info/reference.html It's a combination of two advanced features.

Comment: What expression? The is no expression in your question.

Answer (score 2):

```
(?s)
```

switches on the [DOTALL](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#DOTALL) flag, which allows `.` to match newline characters.

```
.*?
```

matches any sequence of zero or more characters (*including* newlines because of the `(?s)`) up to the first point where the zero-width lookahead

```
(?=From:)
```

matches.  In other words, it gobbles any characters before (but not including) the `From:` at the start of the first email message in the string you're matching against.